# Confirm if link is disabled selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium

The below code finds the correct link from an unordered list in a browser, however the `EC.element_to_be_clickable` function doesn't work because if the link wasn't clickable, it will require the browser to be refreshed (to check again).

Instead, is there any way for the link to be checked if it is disabled (and click() if it isn't? The link will come in one of the below formats

```
<a class="Button disabled">Purchase</a>
<a class="Button">Purchase</a>
```

Code below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

try:
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='$30.00']/../following-sibling::div/a[text()='Purchase']")) > 0:
        print("Found, now attempting to click link")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='$30.00']/../following-sibling::div/a[text()='Purchase']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a link is disabled, ie. if its class contains 'disabled', just look for it in its class:

```
try:
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='$30.00']/../following-sibling::div/a[text()='Purchase']")) > 0:
    elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='$30.00']/../following-sibling::div/a[text()='Purchase']")
        print("Found, now attempting to click link")
        if "disabled" in elem.get_attribute("class"):
            print("Link disabled! Refreshing page.")
            driver.refresh()
        else:
            elem.click()
```

Comment: Excellent, thankyou! Is there also a way to find out if it does not contain "disabled"?

Comment: Yes -- if "disabled" not in elem.get_attribute("class")

Comment: Thankyou! Everything works perfectly, except the element isn't being clicked when instructed to do so. I've tried both methods, elem.click() and trying by going down the original find_element(By.XPATH..) Any ideas? I needed to indent the elem = line in your suggestion to get the code to run, would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Oh yes, possibly, sorry - need to indent it.

Comment: Yep - did that, but for some reason the elem.click() doesn't work. I can't figure it out, any ideas?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? I'm guessing multiple elements are found...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237360/discussion-between-alichino-and-user1345331).